# Automatic Updates in ArcGIS Online for one layer in multiple groups

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

I am creating group maps on ArcGIS Online for my organisation. A lot of these groups will use the same layers but need to be in separate groups as some will have access to sensitive data.

The groups were originally hosted as services on the portal but due to access to the server they are moving onto ArcGIS Online in order for ease of access and to allow multiple people to edit.

Is it possible to have multiple layers in multiple different maps (groups) and them all update simultaneously when they are updated in either ArcGIS Pro or the layer updated in ArcGIS Online?

Comment: I think so but you will need to explore scripting using the ARCGIS Python API. I would explore if you can do this before committing too much.

Comment: If you are working with feature services you can use 'feature views'. See here for more info:https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/data-management/mapping/getting-started-with-hosted-feature-layer-views/